# Why can I ref return an item of an array that only exists inside the method?

Tags: ref, c#-7.0

I was trying out the new ref returns of C#7.

I am able to compile and build this:

```
        public ref string MisUseRefReturn(int index)
    {
        string[] array = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
        return ref array[index]; //array[2] gets out of scope when this method returns!
    }
```

According to MSDN: The return value cannot be a local variable in the method that returns it; it must have a scope that is outside the method that returns it. It can be an instance or static field of a class, or it can be an argument passed to the method. Attempting to return a local variable generates compiler error CS8168, "Cannot return local 'obj' by reference because it is not a ref local."

So why does this compile? When I execute this method, the returned reference shows the correct string.

Comment: "It can be ... of a class".  Arrays are classes.  Allocated on the GC heap so the reference stays valid beyond the method call.  Only ever do this if you intend to modify the array content.  With, say, MisUseRefReturn(0) = "foo";  Which of course makes zero sense in this snippet since there is no way to get a reference back to the array.

Comment: When the method ends, the stack frame is popped. You can't still have references to that destroyed frame. Luckily, the array lives in the heap, not the stack, so it can still be referenced after the method returns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the description [here](https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2017/02/01/refreturns/):

> Returning a local int variable instead of an array is not possible.
>   int is a value type, and thus the variable gets out of scope at the
>   end of the method, and thus a reference to it cannot be returned.
>   That’s different with an array. An array is a reference type, and the
>   array is allocated on the heap. An int within the array can be
>   returned with the ref keyword.

You could not return an integer value directly as it is a value type. An array element can be returned because it is a reference type. The MSDN statement is correct.

> ... of an array that only exists inside the method

The returned reference persists the array beyond the method call.

Answer (score 14):

Think of the array element as if it were an instance field of the array. Imagine your array were:

```
public class FourElementStringArray
{
    public string element0;
    public string element1;
    public string element2;
    public string element3;
}
```

Then your code is equivalent to:

```
public ref string MisUseRefReturn(int index)
{
    var array = new FourElementStringArray
    {
        element0 = "a",
        element1 = "b",
        element2 = "c",
        element3 = "d"
    };
    // TODO: do this dynamically based on index
    return ref array.element2;
}
```

That abides by the piece of documentation you quoted:

> It can be an instance or static field of a class, or it can be an argument passed to the method.

Is this useful? Not particularly. Is it dangerous? No.

The latter part is the important point. Using the regular array, if the caller assigns a new value, that's fine - it's replacing an element of an array, on the heap. The array can't be garbage collected while the array element reference exists; all is basically okay.

What the compiler rule is trying to prevent is the use of a returned reference to somewhere on the *stack* which has then been popped by the method returning. The array itself isn't on the stack, so there's no problem here.

Comment: Then why does it not compile if I return a reference to a local string variable? Isn't that string stored on the heap too?

Comment: @Coder14: The string itself is, but the *variable* isn't. The type of the local variable itself doesn't matter - the important thing is that you can't return a local variable by reference, because by the time the method returns, that variable won't exist any more. That isn't the case when you return an array element or a field within a reference type object by reference.