# Why can I not return a reference to a dictionary value?

Tags: ref, c#-7.0

```
public class PropertyManager
{
    private Dictionary<ElementPropertyKey, string> _values = new Dictionary<ElementPropertyKey, string>();
    private string[] _values2 = new string[1];
    private List<string> _values3 = new List<string>();
    public PropertyManager()
    {
        _values[new ElementPropertyKey(5, 10, "Property1")] = "Value1";
        _values2[0] = "Value2";
        _values3.Add("Value3");
    }

    public ref string GetPropertyValue(ElementPropertyKey key)
    {
        return ref _values[key]; //Does not compile. Error: An expression cannot be used in this context because it may not be returned by reference.         
    }

    public ref string GetPropertyValue2(ElementPropertyKey key)
    {
        return ref _values2[0]; //Compiles
    }

    public ref string GetPropertyValue3(ElementPropertyKey key)
    {
        return ref _values3[0]; //Does not compile. Error: An expression cannot be used in this context because it may not be returned by reference.
    }
}
```

In the above example GetPropertyValue2 compiles, but GetPropertyValue and GetPropertyValue3 do not.
What is wrong with returning a value from a dictionary or list as reference, while it does work for an array?

Comment: Reference semantics was introduced in 7.2 for value types. Why would you need `ref` in your case of returning a reference type?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann, whilst you are correct, your comment is surely orthogonal to the question? Changing `string` to `int` in the OP's example code still yields the same errors.

Comment: @Lander you should be asking why you can use this with arrays when you can't use it with other containers. [Jon Skeet answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48075085/why-can-i-ref-return-an-item-of-an-array-that-only-exists-inside-the-method/48075165#48075165) this earlier today.

Comment: @Lander indexers on containers with value types return a copy of the value that gets allocated in the stack and will disappear once you exit the method. You can't return that safely with `return ref`. Array indexers though are provided by the CLR itself and return a reference to the value [as shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705583/indexers-in-list-vs-array)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, nowhere in Jon's answer to that other question can I find anything that explains why array elements can be used with ref returns and elements of other collections cannot. All he talks about is stack and heap allocations. A Dictionary is allocated on the heap...

Comment: @DavidArno that's explained inthe second question I linked to, [Indexers in List vs Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705583/indexers-in-list-vs-array). List/Dictionary indexers return stack-allocated copies thus unsafe. Array indexers are special beasts implemented by the CLR itself and return references to the data itself, not a copy of it. The important thing is that those references extend the array's lifetime as if they were fields

Comment: @akos-nagy's answer here explains that nicely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd like to add my answer to the 'pot', maybe it makes things a bit more clear.
So, why doesn't that work for lists and dictionaries? Well, if you have a piece of code like this:

```
static string Test()
{
   Dictionary<int, string> s = new Dictionary<int, string>();
   return s[0];
}
```

This (in debug mode) translates to this IL code:

```
IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<int32, string>::.ctor()
IL_0006: stloc.0
IL_0007: ldloc.0
IL_0008: ldc.i4.0
IL_0009: callvirt instance !1 class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<int32, string>::get_Item(!0)
IL_000e: stloc.1
IL_000f: br.s IL_0011

IL_0011: ldloc.1
IL_0012: ret
```

This, in turn means that what you do with one line of code (`return s[0]`) is actually a three-step process: calling the method, storing the return value in a local variable and then returning the value that is stored in that local variable. And, as pointed out by the links the others have provided, returning a local variable by reference is not possible (unless the local variable is a ref local variable, but as pointed out by the others again, since `Diciotionary<TKey,TValue>` and `List<T>` does not have a by-reference return API, this is not possible either).

And now, why does it work for the array? If you look at how array-indexing is handled more closely (i.e. on IL-code level), you can see that there is no method call for array indexing. Instead, a special opcode is added to the code called ldelem (or some variant of that). A code like this:

```
 static string Test()
 {
    string[] s = new string[2];
    return s[0];
 }
```

translates to this in IL:

```
IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ldc.i4.2
IL_0002: newarr [mscorlib]System.String
IL_0007: stloc.0
IL_0008: ldloc.0
IL_0009: ldc.i4.0
IL_000a: ldelem.ref
IL_000b: stloc.1
IL_000c: br.s IL_000e

IL_000e: ldloc.1
IL_000f: ret
```

Of course this looks like the same as it was for the dictionary, but I think the key difference is that the indexer here generates an IL-native call, not a property (i.e. method) call. And if you look at all the possible ldelem variants on MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes(v=vs.110).aspx), you can see that there is one called **ldelema** which can load the address of the element directly to the heap. And indeed, if you write a piece of code like this:

```
static ref string Test()
{
   string[] s = new string[2];
   return ref s[0];
}
```

This translates to the following IL code, utilizing the direct-reference loading ldelema opcode:

```
IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ldc.i4.2
IL_0002: newarr [mscorlib]System.String
IL_0007: stloc.0
IL_0008: ldloc.0
IL_0009: ldc.i4.0
IL_000a: ldelema [mscorlib]System.String
IL_000f: stloc.1
IL_0010: br.s IL_0012

IL_0012: ldloc.1
IL_0013: ret
```

So basically, array indexers are different and under the hood, arrays have support for loading an element by reference to the evaluation stack via native IL calls. Since the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` and other collections implement indexers as properties, which result in method calls, they can only do this if the method called explicitly specifies ref returns.

Comment: Thanks, this explained it to me.
One remark: I suppose the second code block should be showing an array. Currently it's the same code as the first code block.

Comment: Thanks for the remark, your are absolutely right. Edited the code with the right snippet,

Comment: I wonder if any future version of List/Dictionary will contain methods to return a value by reference, as that's now supported in the language.

ref string = ref dictionary.GetValueByRef(1);

Would be nice.